# C# - AWS SNS List topics

Tags: c#, amazon-sns

Is there any way I can list the available topics in SNS with C#?

I want to display the list in a dropdown of a web application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Anand

Comment: Atleast give me a good reason for the downvote please. Is it a sin to ask such questions here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example for that in the official documentation.

```
// using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
// using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;

var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient();
var request = new ListTopicsRequest();
var response = new ListTopicsResponse();

do
{
  response = client.ListTopics(request);  

  foreach (var topic in response.Topics)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Topic: {0}", topic.TopicArn);

    var subs = client.ListSubscriptionsByTopic(
      new ListSubscriptionsByTopicRequest
      {
        TopicArn = topic.TopicArn
      });

    var ss = subs.Subscriptions;

    if (ss.Any())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("  Subscriptions:");

      foreach (var sub in ss)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", sub.SubscriptionArn);
      }
    }

    var attrs = client.GetTopicAttributes(
      new GetTopicAttributesRequest
      {
        TopicArn = topic.TopicArn
      }).Attributes;

    if (attrs.Any())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("  Attributes:");

      foreach (var attr in attrs)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0} = {1}", attr.Key, attr.Value);
      }
    }    

    Console.WriteLine();
  }

  request.NextToken = response.NextToken;

} while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextToken));
```